# How to declare a c++ string with space

Tags: visual-c++

How do i declare a variable having spaces like the one below

std::string First Name="harry";

in visual studio 2010 it shows error this declaration has no storage or class specified.

Comment: std::string First_Name="harry";

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have variable names containing whitespace.  In fact, white space is what the compiler uses to determine when a variable name, literal, operator, etc., begins and another one ends.

As @DevT mentioned in his comment, one option for simulating whitespace in variable names is to use underscores instead.  So you could try the following:

```
std::string First_Name = "harry";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not have variable names with spaces.
So you have to define them using underscore or use caps as below.

```
std::string First_Name="harry";
std::string FirstName="harry";
```